# Rspec-rails drops migrations after running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec3

Upgrade from Rspec 2.x to 3.x, in a rails project - using Rails 4.1.x.

I'm getting a really odd behaviour happening when I run RSpec. Here is the order of events.

1. Both test and normal environments are fully migrated. I test it.
2. I run rspec with command `$ rspec`
3. Then I can check my migrations , and this is the result (for test only, production does not think it losses migrations): [image]

I can't understand why this drops all my migrations. Maybe it will also help to say: if I try to migrate on test again I get this error: [image]

So first, why would it drop all migrations? It's not ACTUALLY dropping them, they are still there - since the tables are all still there.

[1]:

Answer (score 0):

[Rspec 3 has a new feature](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks) that leverages updates in rails 4.1+ that automatically keeps the development and test schemas in sync.  So this means that if you already ran your migrations in development, you don't need to run them again with `RAILS_ENV=test`.  You can double check that you have this (Rspec 3 default) feature activated by looking in `rails_helper.rb` and seeing if you have `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` set.

Comment: I've seen this, and tried it running with and without `maintain_test_schema!` running - yet the behavior doesn't change. Any thoughts?

Comment: If rails+rspec is maintaining your test DB for you, then you don't need to run migrations when `RAILS_ENV=test`--so why are you trying to run them again?